# How to record with Bluetooth earphone on windows?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, microsoft-teams, zoom-meeting

Use screen recording software:camtasia,faststone capture,any screen recording software available.

Scenario 1:
With wired headset, using screen recording software can record zoom meeting or teams or any online sessions also.

Scenario 2:
With Bluetooth earphone, the above scenario not capturing audio from meetings like zoom or teams.

I can record activities on screen but not from teams or zoom or any meeting application.

I know there is a recording option with those meeting directly but I need to record it separately.

Comment: The device being BT should not have an impact on this. Is the wired headset USB or 3.5mm audio adapter? Have you checked for and installed updated drivers for all system devices?

Comment: yes, 3.5 mm and USB also working for wired.
For bluetooth, I am able to attend calls right, so driver is not a problem I guess.
Only recording the screen during the call is not capturing audio.
Can you try it on your end and check once.
The recorder I tried is https://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDownload.htm
Even, inbuilt app, Voice Recorder, also same issue

Comment: `With Bluetooth earphone` .. then where is the microphone in this scenario?  An `earphone` is not a microphone.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I didn't ask whether BT was working at all. Drivers are not simple "is it working or not" functions, and so even if your BT is working for one function, you should still update it if it is not working for another function, like your case. Update all of your device drivers please, then try again and report back.

Comment: Drivers are up to date.And the devices I tried :sennheiser wired, boat rockers 400, OnePlus pods pro. The first one is wired so working both cases. For other two I can attend teams,zoom calls but can't record them with screenrecorder. You can try or test with any of Bluetooth devices on your machine and try to record the meeting with screenrecorder and check. It is definitely not an issue with drivers. Because normal screen recording works. Which I mentioned clearly in my question already.